# EXT JS 4 Combo set readonly

Tags: extjs

I have a combo who's readOnly is initially set to false. After clicking a button an event is launched and I want the combo now to have a readOnly config of true. How is this possible, I can't seem to find any methods that provide this functionality.

Thanks

My solution to this was

```
combo.setConfig({readOnly : true});
combo.reset();
```

This was before I realized there was a method called setReadOnly(). I knew there had to be a method for this somewhere. Thanks for the answer guys.

Comment: Please post your code as it currently stands - it may be that you've got the solution mostly complete already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't use the [setReadOnly](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Trigger-method-setReadOnly) combobox instance method?

Comment: That works perfectly. I only looked at the methods for the combo, didn't think to look for the trigger. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, the docs can be quite tricky to navigate sometimes unless you know just what you're looking for.